# requests.get(X).json(): JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to grab all the nominated (not won) movies from an api so that I can clean it and see the budgets associated with each movie.

My code:

```
class Oscars():
    '''
    Hits data file url that I downloaded and pushed to git - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TobyChen320/yipitdata/main/data/movies -
    And returns every Oscar nominated movie and its budget along with the average budget.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TobyChen320/yipitdata/main/data/movies'
        # create a list of dictionaries that stores film title, year, url, and budget
        self.losing_films = []
  
    def search(self):
        '''
        Searches the data to return losing movies.
        This will also add the movies that fit the criteria into losing_films.
        '''
        main = requests.get(self.base_url).json()
        yearly_list = main['results']
        # loop through the results from main to get each year's nominations
        for year in yearly_list:
            yearly_films = year['films']
        # loop through each film every year to find the winners
            for films in yearly_films:
                # if the film is not a winner add to losing_films list
                if films['Winner'] != True:
                    loser = {}
                    loser['film'] = films['Film']
                    loser['year'] = year['year']
                    loser['url'] = films['Detail URL']
                    self.losing_films.append(loser)

    def get_budget(self):
        '''
        Returns budget of each non-winning film from its Detail URL page.
        '''
        for film in self.losing_films:
            movie = requests.get(film['url']).json()
            # if there is no budget data; I just set it to None (You can change this to fill the missing value with whatever you desire depending on what you are looking for)
            film['budget'] = movie.get('Budget', None)
```

Error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

If I was to change `if films['Winner'] != True` to `if films['Winner'] == True`; the code runs without a problem but it would be giving me winners instead. I want to know where is the flaw in my logic and how do I address it.

Comment: Check the response code before parsing the JSON.

Comment: What does `print(requests.get(self.base_url))` show?

Comment: The response you’re getting _isn’t_ JSON - you need to check it before decoding.

Comment: @ForceBru `print(requests.get(self.base_url))` gives me 200 for the main api. The problem was accessing certain urls from `films['Detail URL']`. @Markus Rosjat gave me a nice solution that uses `.status_code == 200` (I was unaware something so handy was out there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok lets do some digging and this is just quick n dirty to show that the Details URL sends back dicts without the Budget key ..

```
import requests

test = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TobyChen320/yipitdata/main/data/movies')

foo = test.json()['results']

for f in foo:
    films = f['films']
    for film in films:
        if film['Winner'] != True:
            test2 = requests.get(film['Detail URL'])
            print([ k for k in test2.json().keys()])
```

gets you something like

```
python3.9 ~/test_request.py
[' Production company ', ' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Edited by', 'Language', 'Produced by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
[' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Based on', 'Box office', 'Budget', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Edited by', 'Language', 'Produced by', 'Screenplay by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
[' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Language', 'Produced by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
[' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Box office', 'Budget', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Edited by', 'Language', 'Music by', 'Produced by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
[' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Box office', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Edited by', 'Language', 'Produced by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
[' Release dates ', ' Running time ', 'Budget', 'Cinematography', 'Country', 'Directed by', 'Distributed by', 'Edited by', 'Language', 'Music by', 'Starring', 'Title', 'Written by']
```

as you see there is no Budget key in the first url so you might wanna Check for the key before you try to access the value.

```
if 'Budget' in test2.json().keys():
```

for the thest in my snipet this would only print results with a budget key in it

**Update**

some of your URL's return a status_code that isn't 200 so there wont be data to convert to JSON

```
Les Misérables
http://oscars.yipitdata.com/films/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_(2012_film)
403
```

so you might want to check for the status code before you do .json()

```
def get_budget(self):
    '''
    Returns budget of each non-winning film from its Detail URL page.
    '''
    for film in self.losing_films:
        movie = requests.get(film['url'])
        if movie.status_code == 200:

            # if there is no budget data; I just set it to None (You can change this to fill the missing value with whatever you desire depending on what you are looking for)
            film['budget'] = movie.json().get('Budget', None)
```

Cheers

Markus